# Logging in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I was using **TraceWriter** class to write logs in my azure function. When function was small it was pretty well, I was able to see logs in function **Monitor** section and **ApplicationInsight**.

Now I'm building an application and want to use common logging across the application (Web, Jobs & functions) with DI.

I [saw](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/ILogger) **ILogger** interface, It easily replaced with TraceWriter but for my other application (Web and Jobs), I want to resolve this using my own DI but I'm not able to find out an implemented class.

[Serilog.TraceWriter](https://github.com/StarRez/Serilog.Sinks.AzureWebJobsTraceWriter) looks good, but I don't want to use traceWriter in anywhere in my method parameters.

Any idea how to resolve ILogger or custom implementation? Which will work across the applications, I want to send my logs in ApplicationInsights and want to monitor using function monitor section as well

As of now I am using below custom code

```
public class Log : ILog
{
private static TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"] };

public void Error(string message, Exception ex = null)
{
    telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Error);
    if (ex != null)
        telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
}

public void Info(string message)
{
    telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Information);
}

public void Verbose(string message)
{
    telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Verbose);
}

public void Warning(string message)
{
    telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Warning);
}

public TelemetryClient TelemetryClient
{
    get
    {
        return telemetryClient;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you mean that you want a common logging class using ILogger, which can work in web, web jobs and functions?

Comment: yes, with common place to setup logging sink (as of now Application Insight)

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a way to include the logging in services and I found that you can't use `ILogger` and `ILogger<T>` in both versions as `ILogger<T>` will not show up in the logs of functions.

That's why I've created a [solution](https://github.com/Ruard/ProcsIT.Azure.Functions.DependencyInjection) with dependency injection which uses the `ILogger` for functions and injects `ILogger<T>` for the referenced services.

The advantage is that you don't need to change the code in the referenced services in order to make this work. And the included LoggingService and GenericLoggingService allow you to customize logging.

Please note that this currently is work in progress. I didn't test is on Azure yet.

Comment: It looks good for a small solution but we have a multi-layer project, need to inject ILogger dependency in all class library project (BAL,DAL). I Added my current implemented code.

Comment: I will try your solution, Thanks for putting code in Github